# How to enable or disable Apache modules in a distro-agnostic way?

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, configuration, ansible, distributions

I usually work with Debian/Ubuntu as a basis for Apache and recently learned that commands like `a2enmod MOD` or `a2dismod MOD` are Debian-specific.

Is there a global / distro-agnostic way (maybe with some CM like Ansible or another) to enable or disable modules?

<sub>All I personally enable is `http2`, `deflate` and `expires` (and I use them all-default).</sub>

Comment: https://github.com/PeterMosmans/ansible-role-apache2 might be helpful

Comment: Note that Ansible module *itself* would need to be updated if/when Apache's configuration directives change, so you're back on the hamster wheel.

Comment: See also https://github.com/correcthorse/ansible-httpd

Comment: @JeffSchaller regarding your second comment, do you mean to a "minor" update from say 2.4 to 2.6 or to something else?

Comment: if Apache ends up at version 3, and Debian eventually stops aliasing a2enmod to a3enmod, then eventually the playbook stops working because it's trying to use a2enmod.

Comment: These commands - are actually shell-scripts? I could imagine that those should work on any *nix.

Comment: @Nils me too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The platform independent way would in general be an adding of the according `LoadModule` directives to your Apache configuration. What `a2enmod` does, is linking files with such directives (`.load` files, plus additional `.conf` files, if needed) from `/etc/apache2/mods-available` to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`

Comment: Hello, I misunderstand why you didn't allow thew line break. The answer seems to me to contain two different passages in one passages. It is an accessibility issue, as I see it, to split it to two passages. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The *platform independent* in general is not using *platform specific* tooling.

Comment: Hello poiege, I don't want to use any platform specific tooling. What would be an example or general tooling? Please edit to explain an example.

Comment: Go docker!!!!11